# How to delete a character from the middle of a list in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

So, I have an array called "`char x[]`" and it has a size of 10. So far, I have functions to initialize the list and add to the list. For example:

```
char x[10];
intializeList(x);    //it just sets pointer equal to NULL
addToList(x, 'l');   // addToList increments when it does not equal NULL
addToList(x, 'o');
addToList(x, 'l');
printf("Output will be: ");   //lol         
printIt(x);         // function that prints it when *temp != "\0'
```

This is my addToList function since there seemed to be some confusion:

```
void addToList(char *p, char f)
{
    char *blah = f;
    while(*temp != '\0')
    {
        blah++;
    }
    *blah = x;
    temp++;
    *temp = '\0';
}
```

So, I also have a delete from list function which removes the last `'l'` by `deleteIt(&(x[2]));`

Now, my confusion sets in when I have to write a loop in my delete function so I can remove an element from the middle of list of characters. As of right now, my delete function just has my pointer set equal to `'\0';`. I guess I am confused on the logic on how to remove a character from the middle and then move it down at the end and have NULL stop the loop. For example, if I added `'abcdefghi'` and I wanted to remove the 4th element, `deleteIt(&(x[4]))`, the output should be `'abcdfghi'`.

Comment: what do you mean by "it just sets pointer equal to NULL" ?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Your description says what you are trying to do but not what you have done.

Comment: If your `initializeList()` function sets its argument to `NULL`, then that does not have at all the effect you think it has.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Indeed. Fortunately, it won't have any effect. <g> But I wonder what `addToList()` actually increments and what it tests for NULL. Is he trying to increment `x`?

Comment: Normally you'd just copy each of the elements after the one to delete to the element before it, which basically moves the rest of the array back by one element and overwrites the deleted element.  Also look at `memmove()`.

Comment: Arrays are immutable in java so you will have to either create a new array with one less slot and mirror the values in the new array, or you could simply have a null character at the end of the array and shift the values accordingly.

Comment: @johnBollinger My initialistList() puts NULL as the first position in the array. I use this to detect the end of the data because the array is not always full

Comment: @anatoly THe above comment explains what that functions does. It does indeed give the output I have above.

Comment: @rudyVelthuis AddToList function has been posted for you to see

Comment: @scarecrow, (1) the question is about C, not Java.  (2) C arrays have fixed *length*, but they are not immutable.  (3) reducing the array length anyway seems unlikely to be the desired effect.

Comment: @CodeFreak, setting the value of the pointed to element is much different from setting the value of the pointer itself.  Additionally, `NULL` is a null pointer constant.  You should not be assigning `NULL` to a `char`; instead assign the null character, spelled `'\0'` or simply `0`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I apologize about the confusion but I have in fact been using the '\0' as NULL

Comment: @CodeFreak: what is `temp`? Does `char *blah = f;` actually compile? Or is this not your actual code? And I don't see any checking for `NULL`, you are checking for the null character, which is quite something different. `NULL` is a pointer. I hate to say it, but this is a bad question with bad code.

Comment: @CodeFreak: why don't you simply show us all the relevant code, instead of describing it? And show all relevant variables (like `temp`) too. Why is `temp` not a local variable?

Comment: @RudyVelthius I apologize but BLUEPIXY knew what I was attempting to get at. I left out the code that I didn't think was necessary because I did not feel like typing 4 files of code and thought I had enough there for help. But yes, everything compiled.

Answer (score 2):

If you are changing the array in place, you just need to copy over the characters that follow the deleted character 1 place behind (or 2 places if you delete 2 characters, and so on). Like this:

```
void delete(char *str, char c)
{
    char *q = str;
    for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if (*p == c) {
            continue;
        }
        *q = *p;
        q++;
    }
    *q = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What that code did was give me 'abcdefghi' and move the 3rd character, 'c' to the end of it

Comment: @CodeFreak Then you did something else wrong.  `char a[] = "abcdefghi"; delete(a, 'd'); printf("%s\n", a);` prints `abcefghi`.

Comment: @Artedfacto so in my deleteIt function I only have one parameter which is char *p. Would I add char c or char x or something else? If I do not add anything I obviously get an error I am just unsure what to add

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an array of `char`, with a null character as a terminating sentinel; that is, a C string.  The function signature implied by your question is

```
void deleteIt(char *to_delete);
```

and evidently you want to perform a *logical* deletion, which is the only kind possible for the array-based representation of your list.  That means that you must modify the values stored in the array, as opposed to being able to make the underlying storage for the target element cease being part of the array.

In particular, to remove the target element from your list while preserving the other elements, you must move each of the following elements forward one position in the list.  And if you think about it, you know how to do that.  What is the value of the next element? Why, it is `*(to_delete + 1)`.  How many do you need to move?  Why, you need to keep going until you've moved up the terminator.

Details are left as the exercise they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void deleteIt(char *s){
    while(*s = s[1])
        ++s;
}

int main(void){
    char x[] = "abcdefghi";

    deleteIt(&x[4]);
    printf("%s\n", x);//abcdfghi
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! thank you. works perfect. Could you explain what the s[1] is doing? so while the position of pointer s = position 1, you keep incrementing?

Comment: `*s = s[1]` : Copy the following element to the current element. when expression(`*s = s[1]`) becomes 0 when  copied `'\0'`(null-terminator), the loop ends.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Just why did you put the s[1]? What exactly is that element doing?

Comment: I don’t know what you want to ask. It is simply next elements.